# Error in correlation(group5) : could not find function "correlation"

Tags: r, tidyverse, correlation

I'm completely new so please explain like I'm a child. Our professor gave us this command to run with a data set (we got the data set and scatterplot working) but I get

```
Error in correlation(group5) : could not find function "correlation"
```

the command we were told would work is:

```
correlation(group5) %>%
summary() %>%
plot()
```

​

is there another package I should install into R to make it run? We already have tidyverse and magrittr

We are expecting a correlation table but we can't even see it because the command does not exist

Comment: A quick search in [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=correlation) suggests you might be looking for `correlation::correlation()`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=correlation) suggests you might be looking for `correlation::correlation()`.

```r
library(magrittr)

correlation::correlation(mtcars) %>% summary() %>% plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>